# Jarvis instalation issue " OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367 "

Tags: docker, containers, nvidia, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvidia-docker

I am trying to install Jarvis using this instructions:
https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/collections/nvidia:jarvis . Unfortunately when I run jarvis_init.sh I get following error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:495: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: driver error: failed to process request: unknown.
> Error in downloading models.

I have tried restarting docker and PC, but it didn't help. I am using Docker Desktop with WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04. Any help or advice will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.